# How to extract Keras layer weights as trainable parameter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a GAN-like models, but not exactly the same. I'm using Keras with TensorFlow backend.

I have two Keras models `G` and `D`. I want to output the **weights parameter** of a target layer in `G`, as **the input of model D**, and use the result of `D.predict(G.weights)` as part of the loss function for `G`, i.e. `D` is not trainable, but the argument `G.weights` are trainable. In this way to want to further train `G.weights`.

I tried to use

```py
def custom_loss(ytrue, ypred):
    ### Something to do with ytrue and ypred
    weight = self.G.get_layer('target').get_weights()
    loss += self.D.predict(weight)
    return loss
```

but apparently it does not work since `weight` is just a numpy array and is not trainable.

Is there a way to get the weights of model that is still trainable in Keras? I'm new to Keras and know very little about TensorFlow. I will be very appreciate it someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, `layer.get_weights()` will return the *current* weights of the matrix. What you want to feed for prediction is a the node in the computation graph representing such weights. You can use `layer.trainable_weights` instead, which will return two `tf.Variable` which you can feed to another layer/model.

Note that there is one variable for the unit to unit connections and another one for the bias. If you want to get a flattened tensor from it you could do something like:

```py
from keras import backend as K

...
ww, bias = self.G.get_layer('target').trainable_weights
flattened_weights = Flatten()(K.concat([ww, K.reshape(bias, (5, 1))], axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need. May I ask you another question below? Really appreciate that!

Comment: Also, I have another question to ask: is it possible for me to sort the trainable parameters in Keras? I want to do something like `K.sort(layer.trainable_weights)` before feed into other operations, how can I do that?

Comment: Glad to be helpful! I guess you could apply the `K.sort` to the flattened weights. Anyway, that looks like a very strange need to me. If you want to explain further so the answer is more accurate, please write a dedicated post.

Comment: See https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4209#issuecomment-545971502.